Which way to dynamically change the content of the panel is better:: if-else or subpanels_with_poll?
I want to dynamically change the content of the Panel.(Template_icon which depends on selected object)
I found two ways to do this.

if - else

import bpy

class MainPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = 'Main Panel'
    bl_idname = 'SOME_main_panel'
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'SomeCategory'

    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text='Main Panel Label') 
        row2 = layout.row()
        row2.prop(context.scene, 'option')       
        row2.label(text='Main Panel Label') 
        row3 = layout.row()
        if context.scene.option :
            row3.label(text='Option #2') 
        else:
            row3.label(text='Option #1') 
        
def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.option = bpy.props.BoolProperty(name='', default=False, options=set())
    bpy.utils.register_class(MainPanel)

def unregister():
    del bpy.types.Scene.option
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MainPanel)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()


2 subpanels with opposite poll functions

import bpy

class MainPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = 'Main Panel'
    bl_idname = 'SOME_main_panel'
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'SomeCategory'
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text='Main Panel Label') 
        row2 = layout.row()
        row2.prop(context.scene, 'option')       
        row2.label(text='Main Panel Label') 
        
class SubPanel1(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = 'SubPanel option #1'
    bl_idname = 'SOME_inner_panel_option_1'
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'SomeCategory'
    bl_parent_id = MainPanel.bl_idname
    bl_options = {'HIDE_HEADER'}
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return not context.scene.option
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text='Option #1') 
        
class SubPanel2(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = 'SubPanel option #2'
    bl_idname = 'SOME_inner_panel_option_2'
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'SomeCategory'
    bl_parent_id = MainPanel.bl_idname
    bl_options = {'HIDE_HEADER'}
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.scene.option
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()        
        row.label(text='Option #2') 
        
        
def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.option = bpy.props.BoolProperty(name='', default=False, options=set())
    bpy.utils.register_class(MainPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(SubPanel1)
    bpy.utils.register_class(SubPanel2)
    
def unregister():
    del bpy.types.Scene.option
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MainPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SubPanel1)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SubPanel2)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()

Which way is better? Or maybe there is a third one?
I did not find any direct instructions or advice on how we should do this.
Thanks in advance.

I think the performance is similar. Use the time module to check it.

Hello ! The two solutions offer different functionality, it's impossible to answer the question because it depends on a lot of subjective factors. IMO option 1 is more compact but less extensible and option 2 is less compact but more extensible and re-usable. What do you prefer, personally ?

To be honest, I thought that the first option is not conventional. The second option has problems with updates - sometimes strange shifts and artifacts appear.
